# change index value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I change the value of the index in a pandas dataframe?

for example, from this:

```
In[1]:plasmaLipo
Out[1]: 
         Chyloquantity  ChyloSize  VLDLquantity  VLDLSize  LDLquantity  \
Sample                                                                 
1010107          1.07       87.0         115.0      38.7        661.0   
1020107          1.13       88.0         119.0      38.8        670.0   
1030107          0.66       87.0         105.0      37.7        677.0   
1040107          0.74       88.0         100.0      38.1        687.0   
...
```

to this:

```
In[1]:plasmaLipo
Out[1]: 
         Chyloquantity  ChyloSize  VLDLquantity  VLDLSize  LDLquantity  \
Sample                                                                 
1010             1.07       87.0         115.0      38.7        661.0   
1020             1.13       88.0         119.0      38.8        670.0   
1030             0.66       87.0         105.0      37.7        677.0   
1040             0.74       88.0         100.0      38.1        687.0   
...
```

i.e. use only the first 4 digits of the index.

I tried to convert the index in a list and then modify it:

```
indx = list(plasmaLipo.index.values)
newindx = []
for items in indx:
    newindx.append(indx[:3])
print newindx
```

but gives me back the first 3 elements of the list:

```
Out[2] [[1010101, 1020101, 1030101], [1010101, 1020101, 1030101], .....
```

Comment: IIUC then `plasmaLipo.index = plasmaLipo.index.astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the index to `str` dtype using `astype` and then slice the string values, cast back again using `astype` and overwrite the index attribute:

```
In [30]:
df.index = df.index.astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)
df

Out[30]:
        Chyloquantity  ChyloSize  VLDLquantity  VLDLSize  LDLquantity
Sample                                                               
1010             1.07       87.0         115.0      38.7        661.0
1020             1.13       88.0         119.0      38.8        670.0
1030             0.66       87.0         105.0      37.7        677.0
1040             0.74       88.0         100.0      38.1        687.0
```

what you tried:

```
for items in indx:
    newindx.append(indx[:3])
```

looped over each index value in `for items in indx` but you then appended a slice of the entire index on the next line `newindx.append(indx[:3])` which is why it repeated the first 3 index values for each index item

it would've worked if you did:

```
for items in indx:
    newindx.append(items[:3])
```